# How to Terraform import azurerm_postgresql_active_directory_administrator for a postgresql flexible server on Azure

Tags: postgresql, azure, terraform, azure-active-directory, terraform-provider-azure

I created a PostgreSQL flexible server on Azure manually, since there is an error creating it through Terraform. When creating the flexible server, there is an option to select AAD Server admin:

[image]

After creating the whole resource, I am trying to import it into Terraform.
For specifying the AAD Server admin, I tried using the following resource: "azurerm_postgresql_active_directory_administrator". For that resource, the import command that is available inside the documentation would be:
`terraform import azurerm_postgresql_active_directory_administrator.administrator /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/myserver`

My question is, is there an alternative for this, can this "azurerm_postgresql_active_directory_administrator.administrator" resource even be used for flexible servers? Does it need to be used?

I tried using my flexible servers resource ID, but I get the following error:

`Expected a Server ID that matched: │  │ > /subscriptions/12345678-1234-9876-4563-123456789012/resourceGroups/example-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/serverValue │  │ However this value was provided: │  │ > /subscriptions/<my__sensitive_subscription_id>/resourceGroups/hrpap-dev-db-postgres-rg/providers/Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers/hrpap-dev-db-postgres-database-flex/administrators/<object_id> │  │ The parsed Resource ID was missing a value for the segment at position 6 │ (which should be the literal value "servers").`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is a new resource for that, with a little bit different configuration required:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/postgresql_flexible_server_active_directory_administrator